# Auto resize mask for custom view in tab bar view controller not working

Tags: ios6, autoresize

I have a custom view in a tab bar view controller. I have set the autoresize mask for the custom view but it is not getting aligned on the iphone 5 screen. It looks fine on the iphone 4 screen. I have this code in the view did load method of the tab bar view controller.

```
self.customBadge = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:[AppGlobals sharedInstance].badgeNumber];


     self.customBadge.frame = CGRectMake(165, 420,  self.customBadge.frame.size.width,  self.customBadge.frame.size.width);
    self.customBadge.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [self.view addSubview: self.customBadge];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are adding your badge with coordinates according to the whole view of the TabBar (Most screen)

Try:

1. Adding the badge as a subview of the tabbar view itself (You may want to lower the frame's Y from 420 to about 5-10):

   `[self.tabBar addSubview:self.customBadge];`
2. If (1) is not working for you, you may try a hard coded y value (**this is bad practice**, but if you're stuck - it should work):

   `#define VALUE_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular, longScreen) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : longScreen)`

   ...

   `self.customBadge.frame = CGRectMake(165, VALUE_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(420,508),       self.customBadge.frame.size.width,  self.customBadge.frame.size.width);`